# how do i add a custom image dataset from kaggle to Metalhead.jl/Flux.jl julia

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I am new here.
I have been trying to use Metalhead.jl/Flux.jl to train custom image classifiers but I cant seem to be able to load data from a folder directly. (Not part of the standard datasets).
Say I have a folder with 10 sub folders -> each of them with a 1000 images.
How can I load this up to perform a simple leNet5 CNN task?

Thank you!